# postgresql avg(count) for groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, person and violations. Person table consists of the following columns: id,name,DOB while
violations table: violation_id,person_id .

(Violation_id is not a key since more than one person can be involved in the event.)

I want to find the average number of violations for every age group: 18-40, 41-65 and 66+ . So, here is my first attempt that returns the same result for every group. Can anyone guide me through this problem? Thank you in advance.

```
WITH ages AS

(
select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(cast(DOB as date))) as age
from person
)

SELECT
   avg(violation_count) AS avg_violation_count,
 
   case

                    when  age between 18 and 40 then 1
                    when  age between 41 and 65 then 2
                    when  age >= 66 then 3
    end as age_category

FROM  (Select count(violation_id) as violation_count
   from violations
   group by violation_id) V, ages

natural join violations

group by age_category
;
```

Comment: What is the "average number of violations"?  I understand what a *count* is, but not an average number in this case.

Comment: Total number of violations is 1000. To explain thhe average number of violations per group i will give you this example :  in group 1 lets say i have 100 violations, so I am trying to get the result of 100/1000 (avg of group 1). And the same for the rest of the age groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- first calculate the number of events groupwise
- using subquery calculate the Percentage

You need to write you query like this

```
select 
age_category, count_, (count_*100)/sum(count_) over() "avg_violation_count"
from(
select 
case
when  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(cast(DOB as date))) between 18 and 40 then 1
when  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(cast(DOB as date))) between 41 and 65 then 2
when  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(cast(DOB as date))) >= 66 then 3
end as age_category, count(*) "count_"

from
person t1 inner join violations t2 on t1.id=t2.person_id
group by 1
) tab
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=99cbc7714a842ea5677d3b9ff7710d12)

Comment: Thank you very much that was extremely helpful and I managed to solve the problem with your advise!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `join` between the groups -- and I would simply advise you to never use `natural join`.  Just forget that it exists.

If you want to *count* the violations per age group then something like this:

```
select (case when age < 18 then '< 18'
             when age <= 40 then 'between 18 and 40'
             when age <= 65 then 'between 41 and 65'
             else '> 65'
        end) as age_category,
       count(*)
from violations v join
     persons p
     using (person_id)
group by age_category ;
```

You can, of course, just use numbers.  However, this version uses strings so the values are interpretable -- and include under 18s if they have any violations.

If you want the *proportion of all violations* in each group (which is **not** the "average"), then you just use window functions:

```
select (case when age < 18 then '< 18'
             when age <= 40 then 'between 18 and 40'
             when age <= 65 then 'between 41 and 65'
             else '> 65'
        end) as age_category,
       count(*),
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over ()
from violations v join
     persons p
     using (person_id)
group by age_category ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I am trying to make it work by following your lead. Problem is that it still does not return the average number of each age group.

Comment: @Maria just add avg(name) after count(*) :-) I cannot edit due to this msg "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!"